# Azure Servicebus WCF Relay, Address is already in use by an existing listener with different settings

Tags: azure-servicebusrelay

I'm trying to get an Azure Servicebus WCF relay to work following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-relay-tutorial

While following the steps I ran into this exception: System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException

In this case the exception message was "**This endpoint requires IsDynamic = False**". That I could fix by explicitly setting this property to false.

After this fix still the same AddressAlreadyInUseException

However the message now changed to "**Address sb://[namespace].servicebus.windows.net/[WCF Relay name] is already in use by an existing listener with different settings**"

I really can't understand where this error comes from, as it's a newly created WCF Relay endpoint and no other listeners are running. What could be causing this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I'm finding exactly the same thing!

Comment: I think it only happens if you set Requires Client Authorization = False against the relay

Answer (score 0):

- Are you creating a WCF Relay explicitly in the portal (or with NamespaceManager.CreateRelay[Async]) for this endpoint? If so, then you need the binding's IsDynamic == false). If you're not pre-creating the endpoint then the binding's IsDynamic must be true.
- Are you using NetTcpRelayBinding or some other relay binding?
- If you try again after ~30 minutes do you get the same errors?
- If you try with a different WCF Relay(endpoint) address do you see the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

We just had this happen for a really strange reason so am posting here in case it helps anyone else.

Someone configured a tenant with a service path of ./.  This made it so the root path was taken and then every tenant that tried to register would get the error "Address sb://[namespace].servicebus.windows.net/[WCF Relay name] is already in use by an existing listener with different settings".  When we turned off the bad endpoint all the other endpoint were able to work again.